# How to install cbexport and cbimport on a standalone linux vm to connect to remote couchbase server

Tags: database, export, couchbase

I need to use cbexport to export buckets in couchbase and place it in S3. Although I have the credentials to access couchbase I cannot login to the vm on which it is running. So I cannot use the cbexport command available on couchbase vm. Is there a way to install cbexport/cbimport command on a different linux vm? When I search for installation I get links to the command usage rather than installation via apt-get or similar

Do I really need to install Couchbase server in order to get access to the cb commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no standalone tools package available yet. It's something that's been in the backlog for a while: https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-16505